# django: reverse and strip html element id from url

Tags: django, django-views

My `UpdateView` has a `get_success_url()` method that looks like this

```
def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, MESSAGE_UPDATE_SUCCESS, extra_tags="alert-success")
        return reverse('url_name')
```

It submits the form, adds a message on success and redirects back to the same page.

The message is rendered at the top of the page but when the request come from an url of the type `/url_name/#elementID` the reverse comes back to the same url thus hiding the message if the element with id `elementID` is too down in the page.

For preventing this situation I want to reverse to the same page but stripping the id part from the url, thus to `/url_name/` and not to `/url_page/#elementID`

The relevant part of `urls.py` is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^url_name/', login_required(SomeView.as_view()), name='url_name'),
    ]
```

Comment: The urls returned by `reverse` should not include the `#`. Can you show your url patterns?

Comment: The code you've shown also doesn't submit any form, is there any code missing here? (I don't think its the cause of the issue though)

Comment: @Sayse I haven't showed the code for submitting the form, that part of my code works and I agree with you, that part should not be the cause of this issue

Comment: I found a solution, I don't think the problem is django but anyway this works. I just change the opening tag of my form to `<form method="post" onsubmit="window.location.hash=' ';">`. This changes the hash to an invalid ione before submitting the form so the redirected page will be shown at top position